# mit-scheme 9.2 on fedora 21 - installation fails

Tags: installation, fedora, mit-scheme

Following the instructions from the offial page, under https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Unix-Installation.html  ,
I tried to install the mit-scheme on my new Fedora21 machine .

Anyhow, after a good configuration, the making fails with the following lines:

```
Makefile:246: recipe for target 'prdb4.o' failed
make[1]: *** [prdb4.o] Error 1
rm cmpauxmd.sMakefile:246: recipe for target 'prdb4.o' failed
make[1]: *** [prdb4.o] Error 1
rm cmpauxmd.s
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/mitscheme-failing/mit-scheme-9.2/src/microcode'
Makefile:865: recipe for target 'compile-microcode' failed
make: *** [compile-microcode] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/mitscheme-failing/mit-scheme-9.2/src/microcode'
Makefile:865: recipe for target 'compile-microcode' failed
make: *** [compile-microcode] Error 2
```

So, I tried compiling the sourcecode ... ; it fails with a similar message . Since its saturday I suppose the guys at MIT are on vacation, no use to ask them before monday ... - thats why I post it here .

Answer (score 1):

I now solved it, had to remove the prdb4- module ; the solution is described in detail on the following page:
    http://netspectre.de/mitscheme92/

Also there is a sane package for download . The MIT-guys might work it out a better way, when they come along , best regards .